# Change Azure Cloud Service environment variable without publishing

Tags: azure

Is it possible to change an environment variable on an Azure Cloud Service without publishing? I'd like to be able to change a variable and then restart my app, but I don't need to re-deploy.

Comment: By environment variable, do you mean the settings you define in config file (*.cscfg)?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have defined them in the config file, but I wasn't sure if that was the only place they could be defined. I guess if it is, I'll have no choice but to deploy every time I want to change them.

Comment: Actually if they are defined in the config file (in cscfg file and not web/app config file) and you want to change the value, you don't have to redeploy your application. You can simply change the value through portal and be done with it. However if you define a new setting, then you would have to redeploy your application.

Comment: @GauravMantri Ah, interesting. Where do I find that in the portal? Do you know of any way to push an environment variable change via cmdlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the configuration settings in the portal, login into the [`portal`](https://manage.windowsazure.com) (Please note that currently the preview portal does not support cloud services) and the select your cloud service and then click on `CONFIGURE` tab. You will see all settings there.

You can also change the configuration settings through Azure PowerShell Cmdlets as well. So what you would do is make the change in the `cscfg` file and then execute [`Set-AzureDeployment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495140.aspx) Cmdlet. Following is an example of changing the configuration file:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Config -ServiceName "MySvc1" -Slot "Staging" -Configuration "C:\Temp\MyServiceConfig.Cloud.csfg"
```

Some points I do want to mention in the answer:

- You can only change the settings stored in *.cscfg file without redeploying your code. If there are settings in your app/web.config file which you want to change, then you would have to redeploy the application.
- If you want to add new settings, then you have to redeploy the application. You can't add new settings dynamically at this time.